# Do you need an empty hand to cast spells?

Tags: spells, spell-components, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

The Weapon Storm spell has a somatic component<sup>1</sup> (CRB p384):

> [...] This damage has the same type as the weapon and uses the same die size. Determine the die size as if you were attacking with the weapon; for instance, if you were wielding a two-hand weapon in **both hands**, you’d use its two-hand damage die.

A weapon with the *two-hand* property can be used with 2 hands, but it is not required.
How can I use a somatic component while holding a weapon in 2 hands?

Is it possible with any spell?

---

1) And verbal, but that doesn't matter now.

Comment: Maybe the somatic component actually requires the weapon. Maybe it involves the caster striking empty space with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## You can cast any spell without material components while holding anything

Somatic components (CRB, p303):

> You can use this component while holding something in your hand, but not if you are restrained or otherwise unable to gesture freely.

Material components

> The spell gains the manipulate trait and requires you to have a *free hand* to retrieve and manipulate a material component.

Unless of course you have a focus that occupies your hand, or you are a Sorcerer, in which case you do not need a free hand for material components either.

Comment: Too much time spent with DnD 5 and 3.5

Comment: I believe the idea here is that you only need one hand to fulfill the somatic requirement, and while you need two hands to _swing_ a two handed weapon, there's no reason you can't briefly take one hand off to cast the spell.  This logic can be used any time you want to know if a caster can cast a spell with a somatic component.

Comment: @Turksarama, that is the idea in DnD 3.5 and 5, but here you can even cast while holding two separate weapons.

Comment: @Turksarama The rule linked states that you explicitly don't need any hands free to use Somatic components.

Comment: Somatic components don't require a free hand, but material and foci do. https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=282 https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=285

Comment: It's a strange rule, it certainly implies any gesture you need to perform magic can be done with a closed fist, but requires you to be able to move your hands relative to each other.

Comment: @Turksarama, if moving your hands relative to each other would be needed, you could not wield a 2 handed weapon properly, _while_ casting Weapon Storm. So not even that is necessary.

Answer (score -9):

While gesturing with fingers while holding a sword is definitely possible, doing it with an item heavy enough to require two hands seems unwieldy at best.

Honestly, the first thing that came to my mind was *Bewitched*.  Yes, the campy show from the 60's.  A nose wrinkle was the rather gimmicky somatic element used by protagonist Samantha.

From the same era, Jeannie of *I dream of Jeannie* had a head nod in addition to folding her arms.  Sans folded arms, both above are gestures easily performed with occupied hands.

We generally think of tracing runes in the air with hands or fingers for the required gestures, but GM's discretion is rule #1, and your magic doesn't need to look like everybody else's magic.  Even different casters in the same environment can channel the same energies in very different ways.

Comment: Hi VoltisArt! Welcome to the RPGSE! Your answer presents an interesting idea from a narrative standpoint, but there are also rules that bear on the matter at hand. Your answer could benefit from including the relevant rule(s) for support or acknowledging what they say in addition to your (I think clever) homebrew answer. You might consider adding this info in to help prevent downvotes. You can read about how to format quotes in the help section [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: To extend Rykara's point, currently this is an untested homebrew suggestion that is lacking support. If you could [edit] in what the rules *do* say and make it clear what your homebrew suggestion is and what the consequences of it may be that would make this a good answer. Good luck and happy gaming